# How to get the local domain ip address by using koaJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I want to get the local domain ip address for geolocation.  But I can only get the internal ip address, which can not be used for geolocation. Here is my code

```
let koa = require('koa');
let request = require('koa-request');
let proxyaddr = require('proxy-addr');
let ip = require('ip');
let app = new koa();

app.proxy = true;

let API_GEO = 'xxx';
let API_WETHER = 'xxx';
let KEY = 'xxx';
let address = ip.address();

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server running on https://localhost:3000')
});
```

How should I change my code to achieve my goal. Can anyone give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if you are getting the **users** ip address with this approach (I guess its your own internal server IP). Koa has a property on the request object for that `ctx.request.ip`. See also original koa docs http://koajs.com.

Next thing then is, how to send his to an external APIi: You could use something like kia-request for this: https://github.com/dionoid/koa-request

```
app.use(function *() {

    var options = {
        url: 'https://your-endpoint.com',   // here you propably can add you request parameters
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
    };

    var response = yield request(options); 
    var result = JSON.parse(response.body);

    console.log(result);
});
```

(adapted from koa-request docs)

Comment: Thank you for your tips. It's really helpful to me. I have another question, how to get the request ip address for geolocation data. Can you see my updated code?

Comment: BTW I found that if I use request.ip. The ip address I got is ::1. which can not be used for geolocation data or local whether. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Reading the koa docs for [request](https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/api/request.md) you should also set `app.proxy` to true:

"`request.ip` - Request remote address. Supports `X-Forwarded-For` when `app.proxy` is true."

So try this one:

 ```app.proxy = true; 
 let clientIP = ctx.request.ip;```

Comment: No, the result is still same. I can only get ::1, not the domain ip address